# Problems setting up a webview in Objective C (iOS 8)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

seem to be having an issue with defining the URL of a web view. The web view is correctly linked up with the storyboard however when I try to get it to display a webpage I get nothing but blanks screen. I've tried using the advice of another question from stack overflow but it hasn't fixed this problem.

header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController3 : UIViewController

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *weatherView;

@end
```

main:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *urlString = @"https://www.eternitywarestudios.xyz";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_weatherView loadRequest:requestObj];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found redoing the webview again from scratch fixed the problem, must have been a config issue.